# How to display the fields of a struct?

Tags: c#, debugging, struct

I created a struct:

```
public struct User {
   public string name;
   public string email;
   public string age;
}
```

Then create one:

```
 User user = new User();
 user.name = "Freewind";
 user.email = "abc@test.com";
 user.age = 100;
```

Then display it:

```
MessageBox.Show(user.ToString());
```

I hope it can print all of the fields of the user struct, but it's not. It just shows:

```
MyApp.User
```

Is there a easy way to display all the fields of a struct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Override the `ToString` method on your struct:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("name={0}, email={1}, age={2}", this.name, this.email, this.age);
}
```

Note that this is not automatic and you will have to manually add any fields/properties to the string.

With reflection you can do something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    Type type = this.GetType();
    FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
    User user = this;

    Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    Array.ForEach(fields, (field) => values.Add(field.Name, field.GetValue(user)));
    Array.ForEach(properties, (property) =>
        {
            if (property.CanRead)
                values.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(user, null));
        });

    return String.Join(", ", values);
}
```

Comment: Can we use reflection to create a common util for this?

Comment: If you have R#, `alt+insert` on struct name, select "Formatting members" and this code will be auto-generated for you.

Comment: @Freewind added snippet using reflection.

Comment: Of course the solution is not to use reflection in a `ToString` override (fugly!). The solution is to (once again) override `ToString` in your derived types.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection and loop through all the properties like following:
      var sourceProperties = typeof(User).GetProperties();

```
  foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
  {
    MessageBox.Show( sourceProperty.Name );
    MessageBox.Show( sourceProperty.GetValue( user, null, null ) );
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Was just to demonstrate you can just concat to a string builder and show only one box.

Comment: if he just wants to display values then overriding ToString() is much better solution

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to display the contents of a struct, after initializing your struct all you need to to is make sure to specify exactly what variable within the new "User" object you want to display. This can be done by adding a period after the new "User" objects name like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(user.name);
```

This will show the "User" object's name. This can easily be done with any of the other user objects variables by replacing "name" with "email" or "age". By the way it's usually better to store things like ages's (or any number) in an "int" or "byte" because that allow's you to change the value much easyier than trying to store a number within a string. Here's an example:

```
public struct User {
    public string name;
    public string email;
    public int age;
}

or

public struct User {
    public string name;
    public string email;
    //use a byte to hold a value between 0 and 255 (most people don't live to be 255)
    public byte age;
}
```

And when trying to display this variable just use "ToString()" after the variables name like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(user.age.ToString());
```

This will convert the int or byte to a string so it can be used within the "MessageBox.Show" method. Hope this helped!

EDIT:
Also when trying to display all the variables within the struct just do this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Name: " + user.name + Environment.NewLine + "Email: " + user.email + Environment.NewLine + "Age: " + user.age + Environment.NewLine);
```

This will display:

```
Name: FreeWind
Email: abc@test.com
Age: 100
```

Within the messagebox.